# ADD A COLUMN WITH SR.NO in Sap.m.table irrespective of other columns

Tags: sapui5

I have a sap.m.table which has content in it, i want to add a column in the same table with sr.no and it should increment and decrement automatically when data is added and deleted respectively.The number should be added dynamically as per the data in the table.
can anyone suggest me good solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get your table's sPath from oContext...

For Example:

```
oTable.bindAggregation("items", {
            path: "/",      //json is an array of rows
            factory: function(sId, oContext) { //this function is applied to each row

                var sPathindex = oContext.getPath();
                var index = parseInt(sPathindex.substring(1))+1;

                var serialNo = new sap.m.Text({text: index });
            }
           return colListItem = new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
                    cells:[serialNo ]
           });
  }
```

Hope this will helps you to solve your problem

Comment: Will this affect on drag and drop case?

Comment: @Codenewbie: Yes this will affect the numbering later when you perform drag and drop functionality. If you are looking for solution, I would suggest to re-config index after drop event.